# Why <%= %> works inside http but not inside https

Tags: asp.net

`<%= 'test1' %>` is showing test1 in http but if I use https then I see XXXX.

Where is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

Strange, it should **not** work in both cases, you should get compiler error: CS1012: Too many characters in character literal.

You should use double quotes, like this:

```
<%= "test1" %>
```

I can't see how uri scheme can change that, and there should be no difference.

Comment: There is a Firewall installed thats blocking asp commands. I tried in a different server with no firewall and I have no problem